# HTML img has unwanted edges

Tags: html, css, image

See anything-pages.com/ and look at World Series 2010 sponsorship logo on left.  There is an edge along the top and left sides of the logo which is rendered in this markup:

```
<div style="position: absolute; float: left; left: 0px;">
    <img width="200" height="200" src="/themes/zen/atdwh_classic/images/2010 JLBB-30 year - sml.jpg">
</div>
```

What's causing that?

The border property is "border: 0 none;"

Comment: in which browser are you seeing this?

Comment: I don't see any border in IE 8 or FF.

Comment: Not seeing it in FF 3.6 and IE8.

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome on Mac OS X

Comment: Also, you only need to specify border: none; That might be confusing whatever browser you're seeing it in.

Comment: Looks fine in Chromium too. The image seems to have a perfectly #ffffff background. The next thing I was going to suggest was no IE support for png transparency, but I checked and there is no alpha channel I can see either. I think John Sheehan has it.

Answer (score 2):

I see the color difference when I lower the contrast of my ultrabright TFT below 50 percent. I copied the image into photoshop and it turns to have a background of `#fdfdfd` while your webpage has a background of `#ffffff`.

So, to fix this problem either make the image background `#ffffff` as well (or better, transparent), or make your site's background `#fdfdfd` as well :)

---

**Update**: anyway, I made it transparent. Replace it with the below image and retry:

[image]